# Setting up SSL for Azure WebApp

Tags: security, azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up SSL for my Azure WebApp via Network Solution's SSL Service. The doubt I'm facing is, Azure asks for a SSL Certification in (.pfx) format (pic given below) and I do not have any sort of certificate with me right now.

[image]

**However, Network Solution console allows me to attach SSL to my existing Domain. Pic given below:**

[image]

My question is, do I go ahead with the Network Solutions based SSL Attachment solution or upload the *.pfx file Azure is asking for in the Management Console? I'm very confused. Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: If you buy the certificate from any entity, you should get 4 .crt files in your email, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869979/how-do-i-create-pfx-certificate-export-for-azure-website-from-network-solutions

Comment: Okay I got the 4 Certificates. How do I add these to the visual studio project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow Brij's link to generate a valid pfx file, then

For a WebApp, go to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), browse to your WebApp >> Settings > > Custom domains and SSL >> Upload Certificate and complete the process to use your certificate.  Set the domain to use the certificate you uploaded.

Comment: I just added the CNAME records for my web application in order to connect my custom domain. It still says that I have not added a CNAME record. Does it take long?

Comment: Make sure in your DNS settings (at the registrar) that the CNAME record is pointed to [yourSite].azurewebsite.net - it can take a while to propogate, but it shouldn't take long.